# Join from table a single date column with another tables date range oracle 11 g

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to build a query from an Oracle 11g database to use in a report. I need to use two tables A and B to get the Table A column date and Table column B Value

Table A :

```
Dt
01/01/2014
02/01/2014
03/01/2014
04/01/2014
05/01/2014
06/01/2014
```

TABLE B:

```
Value      Start Dt     End Dt
XXXX       01/01/2014    03/01/2014
YYYY       05/01/2014    06/01/2014
```

Final Output:

```
A.Dt               B.Value
01/01/2014         XXXX
02/01/2014         XXXX
03/01/2014         XXXX
04/01/2014         NULL
05/01/2014         YYYY
06/01/2014         YYYY
```

Please help to do above in a single sql query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not all joins are equijoins - you can use the `BETWEEN` operator in your join condition.

```
SELECT          a.dt, b.value
FROM            a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.dt BETWEEN b.start_dt and b.end_dt
```

Comment: +1 but why do you align the *second* word of each line? It's ridiculous. Certainly harder to read, and whitespace is only used for readability.

Comment: It's an old habbit - I like to separate SQL reserved words from object names. I admit it probably works better with simpler SQLs (`SELECT col FROM tab WHERE col2 = 'value'`), though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT A.DT ,B.VALUE

FROM A

LEFT OUTER JOIN

(

SELECT START_DT,VALUE FROM B

UNION 

SELECT END_DT,VALUE FROM B

) B

ON A.DT=B.START_DT

ORDER BY A.DT
```

This should give you the intended output.